# Sending a SOAP message 

Tags: java, xml, soap

I'm trying to send a SOAP message.

I'm adding manually header to the message, using the next code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        AmdocsServicesServiceagentLocator locator = new AmdocsServicesServiceagentLocator();
        PortTypeEndpoint1BindingStub port = new PortTypeEndpoint1BindingStub(new URL("http://srvp7rd-tibco.rnd.local:8025/Process/SoapRequests/Amdocs-Services.serviceagent/PortTypeEndpoint1"),locator);
        GetContactRelatedInfo parameters = new GetContactRelatedInfo();
        GetContactRelatedInfoRequest request = new GetContactRelatedInfoRequest();
        request.setPersonID("6610782925");
        request.setPersonIDType("ID number (CPR)");

        /* Creating an empty XML Document - We need a document*/

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

        /* Creating the XML tree */

        /* Create the root element and add it to the document */
        Element root = doc.createElement("mul:MultiTenant");
        doc.appendChild(root);

        /* Adding the child to the root */
        Element child = doc.createElement("mul:OpCo");
        root.appendChild(child);

        /* Add text element to the child */
        Text text = doc.createTextNode("DENMARK");
        child.appendChild(text);

        /* Adding the child to the root */
        child = doc.createElement("mul:BS");
        root.appendChild(child);

        /* Add text element to the child */
        text = doc.createTextNode("ENV3");
        child.appendChild(text);

        SOAPHeaderElement element = new SOAPHeaderElement("" ,"soapenv:Header" , doc);
        element.setActor(null);
        port.setHeader(element);
        System.out.println(port.getHeaders()[0]);
        port.getContactRelatedInfoOperation(parameters);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I don't know why, or how I'm ending up with a message including attributes that i didn't wanted.
For example the output message of the current code is:

```
<soapenv:Header soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="ns1:Document"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
 <mul:MultiTenant xmlns:mul="">
          <mul:OpCo xmlns:mul="">DENMARK</mul:OpCo>
          <mul:BS xmlns:mul="">ENV3</mul:BS>
 </mul:MultiTenant></soapenv:Header>
```

For example, the `xmlns:mul=""` attribute in the `mul:OpCo` tag.
Is there a way to delete that attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't attributes, those are namespace declarations. You're creating elements with the `mul:` namespace prefix, and that prefix has to be defined somewhere.  Java is adding a default empty declaration (`xmlns:mul=""`) just so that your XML ends up being well-formed - you can't use a prefix without declaring it.

If you don't want those declarations, then remove the `mul:` prefix, or define it properly elsewhere in the document. You haven't told us what your document should look like, though, so it's hard to advise you how to do that.

Comment: the header should look like that: 
   <soap:Header>
      <mul:MultiTenant>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mul:OpCo>?</mul:OpCo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mul:BS>?</mul:BS>
      </mul:MultiTenant>
   </soap:Header>

Comment: @Tal: That's not valid XML.  You *must* declare the `mul` namespace.

Comment: so how do i still add the "mul" without have to dealing with the namespace?

Comment: @TalTchernihovski: You can't.  Doing so would be invalid XML.

Comment: are you sure, because the XML that I copied to the comment I wrote earlier was generated by soapUI software

Comment: @TalTchernihovski: Then you missed something.  Go back and look at it again, the `xmlns:mul` declaration has to be there somewhere. Don't just look at the header, look everywhere.

Comment: OK, but I must make my XML look exactly like the one generated by soapUI, because I'm afraid that if I'll add or change a namespace, it will make the web service reject my XML.

Comment: @TalTchernihovski: I think you need to go and find a tutorial about XML namespaces, you'll find it much easier to follow this problem with a bit of background.

Answer (score 1):

You message doesn't have a declaration of the `mul` namespace. Add it, and the strange `xmlns:mul` attributes should go away.

**Update**

Now I understand, you just create a fragment of a soap message. This is just the header and the `mul` namespace may be declared on the other SOAP-Envelope element.

You **need** to know the namespace(-name) of `mul`, double check the full SOAP message in soapUI and double-check the documentation. Then declare the namespace on `doc`. Later, if the outer element declares `mul` exactly the same way, the attributes should disappear from the serialized xml.

Comment: the header should look like that: 
   <soap:Header>
      <mul:MultiTenant>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mul:OpCo>?</mul:OpCo>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mul:BS>?</mul:BS>
      </mul:MultiTenant>
   </soap:Header>

Comment: so how do i still add the "mul" without have to dealing with the namespace?